# My navbar is under my content during scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, navbar, bootstrap-5

When I load my website everything is in the right places but when I start scrolling my content goes on my navbar and hide in the top of the screen (my navbar is partial visible when I scroll my content but is still on the top of my page) but I want to have my navbar on the top of my screen all the time and my content hide under my navbar.

my navbar code:

```
<a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="/">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="img/full_trimmed_transparent_base (3).png" width="381"height="76" class="d-inline-block mr-1 align-bottom" alt=""></a>
</a>

<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainmenu" aria-controls="mainmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="...">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainmenu">

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/home"> START </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/about_cattery"> O ... </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"> ...</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " href="#"> ...</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"> ... </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">...</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/kontakt"> ...</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav sm-icons">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/...
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-square icon"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

my css navbar :

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(240,240,240,0.5);
    width: 100%;

}

.nav-item {
    font-size: 100%;
     padding-left:3px;
     padding-right:3px;
}

.icon {
    color: #3b5998;
    font-size: 120%;
}

.icon:hover {
    color: #92a6d3;
}

.scrolled {
    background-color: rgba(240,240,240,0.9) !important ;
}
```

content-css:

```
body {
    padding-top: 120px;
}
```

Comment: The last `li` element in your question has a not properly closed `href` inside the `a`. Also could you provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a high z-index to your navbar to keep it above other elements (with a lower z-index):

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(240,240,240,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999999;
}
```